# Telegram user authorization using API

Tags: api, telegram

I am using python with telepy library and try auth user.
I using "auth.sendCall" method and i receive sms with code on my phone.

But in answer from server I can't get sms code hash.

This is decrypted data without server_salt, sess_id, message_id, seq_no, message_len_data

decrypt data = "m\�ԧ} m`W��"7�y�551592c169f53de80a"

bytes from 0 to 4  --  "m\�"  --  type id = -212046591 = RpcResult

first param of rpcresult is "req_mes_id" -- type: "long", take 8 bytes
bytes from 4 to 12  --  "�vr`W" = 6296157737038545920

second param of rpcresult is "result" -- type: "object"
bytes from 12 to 16 -- '��"'  = 571849917  --  of this type doesn't exist

what do I do not so?

Comment: what is the full hex value that you received?

Comment: 016d5cf30068a74ed7b66257bdbc1522379779bc1235336164303638343531626333623061356500

Comment: these are the decrypted bytes?

Comment: Yes, is a decrypted data in hex format

Comment: have you applied the code you got from sms?

Comment: see the result i got:` iex(17)> TL.decode b
{%TL.Rpc_Result{req_msg_id: 6296796264871192576, result: %TL.Unknown{}}, <<189, 188, 21, 34, 55, 151, 121, 188, 18, 53, 51, 97, 100, 48, 54, 56, 52, 53, 49, 98, 99, 51, 98, 48, 97, 53, 101, 0>>}
`

Comment: Not sure I know what version you are running, bit I'm, running schema-53, I do not have this Type-code: <<189, 188, 21, 34>>. If you can tell me what version you are running, then i could possibly help you check further

Comment: I am using this scheme https://core.telegram.org/schema/json

Comment: On this page https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode in  "Query example" viewed answer with this code that i received. Probably he was in the old scheme? Why to me such code can come? What the version depends on?

Comment: Indeed, probably this code was applied to 11 Layer inclusive. But why to me the old, but not new code comes?

Comment: can you adapt your telepy library to use a more up-to-date schema

Comment: have you made any progresses on this?

Comment: Yes, it seems, I have understood. Before I didn't send inquiry of invokeWithLayer in which the version is specified. Now everything works, Thanks